# Автомонтирование USB-флэш в Fedora 31 выполняется как "ro"

Tags: linux, администрирование, usb

Проблема в том, что при автоматическом монтировании любого USB устройства, которое система рассматривает как флэш-накопитель (собственно флэш, фотоаппарат, е-book и т.д.) монтирование выполняется в режиме "только чтение" ("ro").

Если устройство отмонтировать и примонтировать вручную, то всё нормально.  Эта проблема наблюдается только в Fedora-31. В Ubuntu и OpenSuse автомонтирование выполняется в режиме "rw" - проблем нет.

Кто знает - где править конфигурацию?

Comment: Попробуйте как тут - https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/mount-usb-drive-read-only-fedora-16-a-923857/

Comment: @DenisE Там пишут про традиционное монтирование - через *fstab*. А в данной ситуации это неприемлемо. Я НЕ знаю, ни UUID, ни label втыкаемого устройства. И даже точку монтирования невозможно задать в *fstab* т.к. я могу воткнуть две (три!!!) флэшки и как прикажете их монтировать на одну точку?!

Comment: В правилах udev.

Comment: @0andriy В папке */etc/udev/rules.d* есть только один файл - *70-persistent-ipoib.rules*  в котором обрабатывается сетевое соединение. Так что автомонтирование обрабатывается как-то иначе.

Comment: При более внимательном изучении оказалось, что папка, на которую монтируется сменный носитель */run/media/<пользователь>* почему-то принадлежит *root*... Я сменил владельца на себя, но лучше не стало: флэшка по прежнему монтируется как *ro*.

Comment: Изучайте, systemd столько всего интересного делает... (Нет, я не в курсе, что там поломано или настроено у вас таким образом)